# Firefox launching jvm with custom parameters

Tags: java, firefox, xulrunner

I am working on an applet that requires -d32 parameter. How can I tell that to firefox or xulrunner? Can I make a custom profile that uses -d32 to launch JVM?

Any help is appreciated,

Thx